# How to add ViewBag numbers which from different Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewbag

I have some ViewBag codes:

```
<p>@(((decimal)ViewBag.InvHardwareTotalPrice).ToString("C2"))</p>
<p>@(((decimal)ViewBag.InvSoftwareTotalPrice).ToString("C2"))</p>
<p>@(((decimal)ViewBag.InvFurnitureTotalPrice).ToString("C2"))</p>
```

They shows the price of items in webpage:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgIQM.jpg)

I want have a space to add the total number of those 3 numbers, I tried but not working:

```
<p>@((decimal)ViewBag.InvFurnitureTotalPrice) + @((decimal)ViewBag.InvFurnitureTotalPrice)</p>
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
<p>
    @{
        decimal totalPrice = ((decimal)ViewBag.InvHardwareTotalPrice) + ((decimal)ViewBag.InvSoftwareTotalPrice) + ((decimal)ViewBag.InvFurnitureTotalPrice);
        @totalPrice.ToString("C2")
    }
</p>
```